# Removing square brackets when using send_keys in Python (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run this code with the user input '111', in the web element it types `[111]`.

How do I remove the square brackets so that it only types `111`?

Seems super simple but can't find a solution anywhere.

```
campaign_text_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']")
user_input_to_string = str(user_input)
campaign_text_field.send_keys(user_input_to_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the second line with this:

```
user_input_to_string = ''.join(x for x in user_input)
```

looks like what you have right now is casting a list to a string. This will concatenate the elements of that list into a string, which is just very subtly different, and probably what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

added `.strip("[]")` to the end of the `user_input_to_string variable` :

```
campaign_text_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search']")
user_input_to_string = str(user_input).strip("[]")
campaign_text_field.send_keys(user_input_to_string)
```

Comment: That might work but it is not a very clean approach: it is still converting a list to a string, then scanning the string again for those characters to remove. It will break if there is more than 1 element in the input.